# I'm trying to get two monitors to run on Windows 10, but my computer isn't detecting the second monitor

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I run 64 bit Windows 10, with an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3gb graphics card (with up to date driver version 26.21.14.3630 direct from the NVIDIA website) and am trying to set up a second monitor. I only have one HDMI port on my computer, so I'm trying to simultaneously run an HDMI cable and VGA cable to the two separate monitors. I'm used to this process being relatively plug-and-play.

Despite having a VGA port, my computer isn't seeming to recognize any monitor plugged in via VGA. Nothing is detected on the Device Manager screen, the Display option in settings, or on the WIN+P menu. I've seen some answers suggesting that these can't be run at the same time, but I'm not versed enough in computers to understand or workaround the issue.

Is there a way, with only one VGA port and only one HDMI port, to run two monitors on my computer? What other information about my computer might you need to provide the answer?

I appreciate your time - thank you!

Comment: Can I assume the outputs from your card are

DP 1.43, HDMI 2.0b, Dual Link-DVI

and you're using a Displayport to VGA adapter? In that case you may need an **active** DP to VGA adapter rather than a passive adapter cable.

Comment: Owain - when I say I'm not versed enough, I mean I had to google each thing you just said. I have a standard VGA monitor cable (one of the two which came with the monitor, the other being HDMI) attached to the back of the monitor, and being plugged into the matching port on the back of my tower. 

Should I disregard the VGA port, and instead use the DP port next to the HDMI port, and get that adapter?

Answer (score 1):

Owain in the comments had me on the right path - I hadn't realized that the VGA port on my computer didn't also go to the graphics card. I bought a $10 DP to HDMI adapter, and am typing this on my dual monitor setup.

I'm an absolute novice, be be gentle!